# Key used by HMAC-SHAx in PBKDF2

Tags: hmac, pbkdf-2

PBKDF2 can be used to derive a key from a passphrase, having in input the passphrase, the chosen number of iterations to slow down a brute force attack, a random salt and the chosen keylength. In its implementation it needs a PRNG which can be, for example, HMAC-SHA-something; but HMAC needs itself a key together with a "message" (which I think is the passphrase in the first iteration, and then its resulting hash in the subsequent ones): so what is this key?

Comment: I've answered, but note that it should be easy to extract this kind of information from the standard. **If unsure, check the standard.**

Comment: Or existing, identical questions(s): http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10164/pbkdf2-uses-hmac-sha1-to-generate-keys-but-what-is-the-key-for-the-hmac?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password, encoded as octet string (usually using ASCII or UTF-8 as encoding), is used as key. The salt is used as data to HMAC.

[The scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-5.2) specifies the following *internal* calculation:

```
U_1 = PRF (P, S || INT (i)) ,
U_2 = PRF (P, U_1) ,
...
U_c = PRF (P, U_{c-1}) .
```

where $P$ is the encoded password, $c$ is the iteration count, $S$ the salt and $\operatorname{INT}(i)$ an indicator of the output block (if more than a single block of output is required from the PRF). The PRF is not found in any other part of the scheme (PBKDF2 is not a complex protocol, you could argue too simple).

The PRF can be any pseudo random function, but it is usually set to HMAC-SHA-1 used as default:

> The default pseudorandom function is HMAC-SHA-1:

in other words, `PRF(P, X)` can be read as `HMAC-SHA-1(P, X)`.

Answer (score 2):

The key is the password.

For the first iteration, the salt concatenated with the desired output length in bytes is the input.
`U1 = PRF(Password, Salt || INT_32_BE(i))`

For subsequent iterations, the HMAC result is the salt.
`U2 = PRF(Password, U1)`
`...`
`Uc = PRF(Password, Uc-1)`